# smooth scroll not working in firefox, works fine in IE

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, scriptaculous

My beloved Firefox is losing to IE on this. Anyone know why this won't function in Firefox? (doesn't even go to anchor), but scrolls smoothly in IE?

```
document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
    if ($$('a.scroll')) {
        $$('a.scroll').invoke('observe','click', function(event) {
            Event.stop(event);
            var elementLink = Event.element(event).readAttribute('href');
            var scrollHere = elementLink.substr(1, elementLink.length);
            Effect.ScrollTo(scrollHere);
            return false;
        });
    }
});
```

applied as such:

```
<a class="scroll" href="#27">test scroll</a>
```

PS: It is prototype/scriptaculous based.

Answer (score 1):

I would suppose that the problem is in numerical anchor. According to standard id attribute of the element should start from the letter.

Comment: No errors in console? It would be great if you could create jsfiddle demo with you script.

Comment: No errors in the console - http://jsfiddle.net/8QMBW/1/ it's not working at all on JSfiddle