# Javascript smooth scroll not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

I made this website: bosd.eu.
It has a piece of javascript/jQuery that focusses on the proper area of the page when clicked.

However, when I use Firefox, either mobile or desktop nothing works.

So It has to be the javascript right?

```
var initSmoothScroll = function(){
    $('.scroll').click(function () {
        doScroll($(this))
    });
};

var doScroll = function($element){
    $('body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#' + $element.attr('target')).offset().top - 10
    }, 300);
};

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100) {
        $('#topbutton').fadeIn('slow');
    }
    else {
        $('#topbutton').fadeOut('fast');
    }
});
```

This is how it is processed in HTML:

```
<a class="scroll" target="story" id="storybutton"><h1>ABOUT</h1></a>
```

I found this when searching, but it did not provide me with an answer:

- [Jquery Auto scroll not working in firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7539324/jquery-auto-scroll-not-working-in-firefox)
- [smooth scroll not working in firefox, works fine in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7025535/smooth-scroll-not-working-in-firefox-works-fine-in-ie)
- [Animate scroll not working in firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27150913/animate-scroll-not-working-in-firefox)

Comment: Why are you using `eval`? I think it's not required there.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I removed EVAL, script is still working fine in any browser but Firefox.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently i needed to add HTML to the body.animate:

```
var doScroll = function($element){
$('body, html').animate({
```

It works flawlessly now.

Comment: I can confirm that this has also solved the problem for me, good work and thanks.